# Problem with stack overflow is forcing device reset

Tags: pic, mplab

I am doing a small voltmeter with PIC18f4550, I am using the ADC converter of the PIC and based on the binary value I receive I show an approximation in a 7 segment display, the problem is that the program stays cycled and does not perform any action. I enclose the code I am using.

```
    list p=18f4550
    include <p18f4550.inc>

    ;CONFIG  FOSC = HS
    CONFIG  PWRT = ON
    CONFIG  BOR = OFF
    CONFIG  WDT = OFF
    CONFIG  MCLRE = OFF
    CONFIG  PBADEN = OFF
    CONFIG  LVP = OFF
    CONFIG  DEBUG = OFF
    CONFIG  XINST = OFF
    ;se utiliza para asignar variables de forma secuencial
    CBLOCK  0x00
        adclecturaH
        adclecturaL
        Tiempo
        aux1
    ENDC
        org 0x00 ;incia desde posicion 0
        goto Inicio
;  
    Inicio
        CLRF PORTB
        MOVLW 0x00
        MOVWF TRISB ;asignar como salidas
        CLRF PORTC
        MOVLW 0x00
        MOVWF TRISC ;asignar como salidas
        MOVLW b'00011110'
        MOVWF ADCON1
        MOVLW b'00000001'
        MOVWF ADCON0                
    Ciclo   
        BSF ADCON0, 1
        BTFSC ADCON0, 1
        MOVFF ADRESH,adclecturaH
        movlw adclecturaH
        movwf aux1
        MOVLW 0X00

    ;-------------------------------------------------COMPROBACIONES
    ;movlw b'00010000'
    COM0 
        movlw b'00000000'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        call COM1 ;otra comprobacion
        call DIS0
    COM1 
        movlw b'11001100'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        call COM2 ;otra comprobacion
        call DIS1
    COM2 
        movlw b'01100110'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        call COM3 ;otra comprobacion
        call DIS2
    COM3 
        movlw b'10011001'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        call COM4 ;otra comprobacion
        call DIS3
    COM4 
        movlw b'00110011'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        call COM5 ;otra comprobacion
        call DIS4
    COM5 
        movlw b'11111111'
        sublw aux1
        btfsc STATUS,Z 
        CALL COM1
        call DIS5
    ;----------------------------------------------MOSTRAR VALORES      
    DIS0 
        MOVLW h'3f'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo      
    DIS1 
        MOVLW h'06'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo      
    DIS2 
        MOVLW h'5b'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo  
    DIS3 
        MOVLW h'4f'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo      
    DIS4 
        MOVLW h'66'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo  
    DIS5 
        MOVLW h'6d'
        MOVWF PORTB
        CALL RETARDO
        GOTO Ciclo

    RETARDO 
        MOVLW D'245' 
        MOVWF Tiempo 
    DEC 
        decfsz Tiempo
        GOTO DEC    
        RETURN
        END
```

The error I receive in Proteus 7 is:

> [PIC18 STACK] PC = 0x0082 stack overflow is forcing device reset

Answer (score 2):

Every `CALL` needs a `RET` statment.
`CALL` will put the PC onto the stack and `RET` will get it back. Without `RET` the stack will overrun:

```
main:
CALL  Subfunc                  ;CALL subfunction
.....                          ;continue here after finish subfunction


Sunfunc:
  MOVLW  0x00                  ;example
  ....
  RET                          ;jump back to main function
```